# How to manage offline data within a lightning components ?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, offline

Can you share some sample of lightning component storing data on device and managing offline ?

Comment: If you're doing a standalone app with a SDK-based wrapper, I think it would be possible to do with Application Cache manifest files, but I haven't seen any examples of doing this yet.

Comment: I agree with Tom. Lightning is inherently a client-side, browser-based framework. To access local files on a physical device would require a native container for iOS, Android or whatever other platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty easily store the results of calls using the cache and Storable within your components.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_storable_actions.htm

As you'd imagine, direct access to the cache is in the works:

[Aura Storage service usage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/125879/aura-storage-service-usage)