# Aura Storage service usage

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pre-release, summer-16

I am looking at Storage Services in Aura framework which can be used to have multiple persistent as well as secure database on client side.

Has anyone tried to use same as when I am stuck at initial phase about how I can initialize the storage. I tried using like -

```
$A.StorageService
$A.AuraStorageService
```

but everytime it comes as undefined. Also I checked $A attributes and it does not have anything related to storage.
Checkied multiple links like - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/storage_use.htm

Also I have added following code in component side as well -

```
<aura:component isTemplate="true" >

    <aura:set attribute="auraPreInitBlock">
        <auraStorage:init name="actions" persistent="false" secure="false"
             maxSize="1024" version="1.0"/>
    </aura:set>
    <ui:button label="Run action at Server and mark as storable"
      press="{!c.runActionAtServerAndStore}" 
      aura:id="ForceActionAtServer"/>
</aura:component>
```

Also I am on a Summer 16 prerelease org which is having API 37 on which it should work.

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 6):

Aura Storage Service's JavaScript API is not exposed in Lightning yet. But it's on the roadmap to expose as a general key-value store. Expect it in the next couple releases (safe harbor).

I'm working to revamp the API to be simpler to use and be more performant. Initial numbers look very promising.

The only supported exposure is  tag. It's most often used to create a stored called "actions" to facilitate caching of storable actions.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, So does that mean I cannot create a storage tag on Lightning component and use it in component controller to set and get values? The official documentation seems to be inadequate. Not getting exactly how can i use the lightning storage tag with controller . Or even in lightning it is just for server side storage? Link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_storable_actions.htm

Comment: The solved use case today is to enable caching of storable actions. That is, the only valuable use of <auraStorage:init> is to create a store called "actions". In the future the JS API will be exposed so a Lightning component can use the storage as a key-value store in which case creating a store other than "actions" will be valuable.

Comment: I was able to get the app working offline after using useAppcache="true" and having the store as actions. whether we can use the same store to store some piece of data is yet to be explored.

Answer (score 0):

So I just ran into this problem myself.  Finally figured out about 3/4 of the way down [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/storage_init.htm) I found

> Server-side actions storage is the only currently supported type of
> storage. Storage for server-side actions caches action response
> values. The storage name must be actions.

So basically no local storage in the current version of the storage service.  Only the server-side cacheing

Comment: Yes I already checked that, but there is also documentation usign AuraStorage https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/storage_use.htm

Comment: Yeah. Misleading for sure. Would need validation from someone at SF but it seems like there is no clientside storage at this time

Comment: Exposure of https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/storage_use.htm was a doc bug. This feature is available in open-source Aura but not in the Lightning Component Framework at this time. We removed this doc. Apologies for the confusion.